# Migrations dependencies: run one by one?

Tags: 8, migrations

I have a few migrations in the same group for singe multi-language entity type set up. One migration handles one language. I need to make sure that default English language migration runs first and then it triggers all the others when I execute migration for the English language via admin UI of migrate tools module.

Can not find how make it through dependencies in yml for the default language, because dependencies list gets processed first. Is there proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you only need two yaml files, one for the default language and one for the translations.

If you are migrating for example a content type of bundle `pages` and your default language migration is eg. `my_website_migrate_node_page`, then in the `my_website_migrate_node_page_translation` define your dependencies as follows

```
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - my_website_migrate_node_page
  optional: { }
```